# What are the best ways for an iOS 9 user to protect against device fingerprinting?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, ios, obscurity, fingerprinting

In response to this series of questions:
[What unique device fingerprinting information can an iOS9 app collect?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96119/what-unique-device-fingerprinting-information-can-an-ios9-app-collect) and as an update to this question: [What are the best practices for maintaining privacy on a non-jailbroken iOS device?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13041/what-are-the-best-practices-for-maintaining-privacy-on-a-non-jailbroken-ios-devi) What practices should privacy-conscious users adopt to minimize the ability for web sites in the browser AND in apps (by the app makers or by 3rd-party services used within apps), to use device fingerprinting to uniquely identify and track an iOS device across web pages or across apps?

I'll also assume that as a first step to avoid device fingerprinting, basic privacy hygiene must be observed: aggressive cookie management, using only a minimal set of trusted apps, etc.

Starter list of basic privacy hygiene practices:

- In Safari Settings: Block Pop-ups ON, Do Not Track ON, Block Cookies
  = Allow from Current Website Only, Clear History and Website Data regularly. Don't reuse private browsing tabs for more than one site.
- Don't allow apps permission to access unique personal data sets like
  Location, Contacts, Calendar (Settings|Privacy). If you use Location Services, disallow it for Weather - there's no "While using the app" choice, and weather.com has a pretty nasty privacy policy.
- Don't add any accounts for app makers that have "integrated" status
  (e.g., Facebook, Twitter), since it's not clear if those apps enjoy
  privileged access to non-public APIs. Best to avoid any apps from
  companies that are ubiquitous trackers around the web (e.g., Google,
  and the others above).
- Turn off Background App Refresh so that apps only access the internet
  when you are actively using them (Settings | General).

Starter list of device fingerprinting counter-surveillance practices:

- In Settings|Privacy|Advertising, turn ON Limit Ad Tracking, and Reset
  Advertising Identifier OFTEN.
- The other persistent identifier is the Vendor ID, which can be reset
  by (temporarily) deleting all apps from a given vendor, then
  reinstalling.
- It may be necessary to completely wipe the device occasionally to
  clear out any persistent iOS Keychain items or iCloud Key-Value
  Stores, especially for apps that have been deleted.
- New in iOS 9, apps are prevented/discouraged from determining what
  other apps are running/installed on your device. Prior to iOS 9,
  minimizing installed apps (to a small set of common apps) and
  frequent force-quitting apps was about the only defense against this.
- Also new in iOS 9 will be the ability to block trackers. Rather than
  minimizing the fingerprinting attack surface, this addresses the
  ability of (3rd-party) trackers to detect that surface. It will be interesting to
  see how this develops.
- Use a common browser to avoid a rare UA. Presumably for now this is
  still iOS 8 Safari (use in Private Browsing mode).
- Change your IP address often, or use Tor or another IP-obfuscating
  tactic (e.g., an always-on VPN). Preferably use an IP address that many other
  users/devices are using as an exit IP address.